# FFmpeg using complex filter amerge doesn't play on iOS

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using 2 different FFmpeg commands to add audio to a video:
This adds audio and replace video's existing audio:

ffmpeg -i "inputVideo.wmv" -i "inputAudio.mp3" -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 "outputVideo.mp4"

It works fine.

The problem comes when I try to mix the new audio with the video's existing audio:

ffmpeg -i "inputVideo.wmv" -i "inputAudio.mp3" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -shortest -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 "outputVideo.mp4"

The video plays fine everywhere but on iOS.  I've tried adding -profile:v main -level 3.1  and -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 but no luck either.

ffmpeg -i "inputVideo.wmv" -i "inputAudio.mp3" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -shortest -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 "outputVideo.mp4"

WHat do I need to do to make the output video play on iOS?

Comment: Share full log. Since amerge op results in additive channel count, my guess is that iOS probably has a limit of 2 channels, Add `-ac 2`as an output option and check.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks

Comment: @Gyan Brilliant! Had the same issue and it fixed it, thank you! And thank you SilenceKit for this question!